# Sending AJAX request to secured websites

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, get, code-injection

I'm currently writing a script that is meant to GET information from a website. What's unique about this website is that it's password protected (user gets prompted an alert with username and password field similar to the prompt when accessing a router). I'm wondering if there's anyway I can have my script inject these fields automatically? Is there anything I can add to the request below to help inject the username and password into the fields? Thanks in advance.

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(data){
      alert(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: does https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Authentication help you ? I remember using a header with the appropriate value (grabbed through dev tools). See last paragraph, about user/password in querystring. Very unsecure however

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inspect the network request in the Network tab of your browser's developer tools and examine the `Authentication` header in the request to figure out which [authentication scheme](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Authentication#Authentication_schemes) is in use. Then you should be able to replicate it using some combination of the `headers`, `username` and `password` options to jQuery's [Ajax method](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). Note that you'll likely have to set `withCredentials` as described on that page too.

Odd are, however, that you will bounce right off the [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) as sites using HTTP authentication are less likely to have granted permission via [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).